# Google Maps street view

Tags: jquery, maps

I am trying to show the street view in a jquery dialog box with a width of 500. What I have is a marker that can be clicked on the map. Once it is clicked I have this myPano.setLocationAndPOV(overlay); set in the markers click event. It works fine on the first click of the marker. However, on the second click for some reason it resizes the street view to around 100px instead of 500. Any ideas why or a way to get it to properly work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the checkResize() method of the GStreetviewPanorama object. (see: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference.html#GStreetviewPanorama).

If you're using v3 of the Google Maps API, then you'll need to trigger the StreetViewPanorama object's resize event.